# Ruby on rails and mobile development using phonegap

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cordova

i am building a light rails app. I am wondering how or what do i do so that when i use phonegap to create an app i can synchronize data from my rails app ?

thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, you've got a Rails app. And then you're creating a Phonegap app. You're asking how best to have your Phonegap app communicate back to your Rails app to push/pull data from your Rails app?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Rails you want to build an API to interact with your data. It's almost trivial to make a REST API but depending on whether you want just anyone making these requests or only your Phonegap app, you'll need to add some sort of API key checking mechanism on the Rails end to "secure" your API. From the Phonegap app, you're going to access this API just like you would for Google Map or Foursquare or whatever.

The Phonegap app is nothing more than a completely standalone HTML5/Javascript app. Any interaction it needs to have to your server has to be done via Javascript making requests back to your server and processing the response and manipulating the HTML/CSS locally.